# How do I multiply each member of an array by a variable scalar in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multiplication, converters

I'm writing a code that multiply each item in array with a variable scalar ( 2**i)

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 4]
for (let i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    let output = // 
}
console.log(output)   // **output = [1*(2**0), 2*(2**1), 3(2**2), 4(2**3)]**
```

Comment: Do you mean `let output = a[i];` ?

Comment: output = a[i] * (2**i) , we use push() or map() for it

Comment: Alright, it just wasn't clear if you knew how to access values from arrays. There are a lot of ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an array out of the for and push the values.

```js
a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  output.push(a[i] * (2 ** i));
}
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` same as :

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const output = a.map((ele, index) => ele*(2**index))
console.log(output) // **output = [1*(2**0), 2*(2**1), 3(2**2), 4(2**3)]**
```